# Mediawiki 404 error on Main Page

Tags: mediawiki

I had a mediawiki installation on an old website, still have the database and all the info that the wiki contained. I basically did a direct FTP transfer of all the old directories to a new website.

I changed in LocalSettings.php the following to account for my new locations:

```
$wgScriptPath       = '/forge';
$wgArticlePath = '/forge/$1';
$wgRunJobsAsync = false;
$wgScriptExtension  = ".php";
```

Really the only thing I had to do was update the script path and the article path to be different from what they were before. All the db login info is the same. Yet I am getting a 404 page not found error when I try to access the site. Something is working properly because when I type in the URL with /forge, it comes up as /forge/Main_Page. Is there some other setting I need to be changing?

Comment: I managed to get this to work properly by editing the LocalSettings.php file, but I had neglected to change the htaccess file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you configure Apache rewrites for pretty URLs like `/forge/Page_title`? Doesn't seem so.
2. Don't point `$wgScriptPath` and `$wgArticlePath` to the same directory. While it's theoretically possible to make it work with more rewrites (e.g. making it differ between `/forge/Page` and `/forge/index.php?...` and so on), this is a pain in the ass to accomplish and is explicitly not supported by MediaWiki developers.